# F# Swap arrays of data and get the correct results

Tags: f#

```
let highs = [| 2; 4; 6 |]
let lows = [| 1; 5; 10 |]
```

I want to get 2 arrays from the above: if the element in highs is smaller than the corresponding element in lows, then swap them.  So, I can get the final 2 arrays:

```
let trueHighs = [| 2; 5; 10 |]
let trueLows = [| 1; 4; 6 |]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar with JaredPar's answer but simpler:

```
let trueHighs, trueLows =        
    Array.zip highs lows
    |> Array.map (fun (x, y) -> if x >= y then (x, y) else (y, x))
    |> Array.unzip
```

Another more concise version:

```
let trueHighs, trueLows =        
    (highs, lows)
    ||> Array.map2 (fun x y -> if x >= y then (x, y) else (y, x))    
    |> Array.unzip
```

Comment: This creates extra arrays, but is probably the canonical functional solution.

Comment: Your second one only creates one extra array (and some tuples), the cost of which is probably offset by my comparing each pair twice. The most efficient solution is assigning each item in a for loop, but F#-ers tend to frown on that (unreasonably IMO).

Comment: Hi, Pad:
Your version is great and its functional, I will use your code.
Thank you very much for your great code!
John

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code you should use:

```
let n = highs.Length
let trueHighs = Array.init n (fun i -> max highs.[i] lows.[i])
let trueLows = Array.init n (fun i -> min highs.[i] lows.[i])
```

If performance is uber-critical, you're probably better off with an imperative approach.

```
let n = highs.Length
let trueHighs = Array.zeroCreate n
let trueLows = Array.zeroCreate n
for i = 0 to n-1 do
  let hi = highs.[i]
  let lo = lows.[i]
  if hi > lo then
    trueHighs.[i] <- hi
    trueLows.[i] <- lo
  else
    trueHighs.[i] <- lo
    trueLows.[i] <- hi
```

Comment: Hi, Danel:
Thank you very much for your code.  Your code is good and easy to understand.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, Danel:
Your imperative code could perform very well, but it is not functional at all.  Since the performance is not very important, I need only to compare at most 300 elements each time, so using functional code looks better and clean.
But thanks for your good code too!
Have a nice day!
John

Comment: @JohnJohn: Arrays are inherently mutable and are typically chosen for performance (if you don't care about that, use lists or sequences). Functional code involving arrays can only isolate mutation, not avoid it but, generally, embracing it yields better results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
let trueHighs, trueLows = 
  let zipped = 
    highs
    |> Seq.ofArray
    |> Seq.zip (lows |> Seq.ofArray)
    |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> min x y, max x y)
  let lows = zipped |> Seq.map fst |> Array.ofSeq
  let highs = zipped |> Seq.map snd |> Array.ofSeq
  highs, lows
```

Comment: Hello, JaredPar:
Thank you very much for your code, your code is rather functional, but not easy.  I think Daniel's code seems to be easy to understand.